# i want to extend from one class but delete some property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, class, oop

I have some class for crud API service class
I want to extend it but spear few properties
for exam this is my class

```
class Parent {
  public propertyToKeep: any;
  public propertyToDelete: any;
  constructor() { }
}
```

this is the child class

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Another file
where I don't want to see and get access to

```
export class comeComponent {
  constructor(private child: Child) {
    this.child.propertyToKeep // work
    this.child.propertyToDelete // error and I can't even see it
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is problem? you have extended a class but you can't see some of the properties in the child class?

Comment: That's not possible. A child class is a full parent class. That's how OOP inheritance works. JavaScript and TypeScript support [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Polymorphism). It requires that every subtype has its parent's properties and methods.

Comment: the best solution i suggest is to make an intermediate class called "SharedClass" which will be the parent of the two classes : parentClass & childClass, which will contains only "shared properties" , like that you will be able to extend from it directly and conserving the parent properties for its purposes .

Comment: You could go back to JavaScript's [prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes). There you can inherit and remove properties.

Comment: I want to extend a class but remove and more important to do it in the easier way, because I have a class that 100 other class extends, and I can't change the class.
I need some function to edit the type and disabled some functions to all my developers extending this class but which don't use some function in it.
vic1707 answer more likely the better.

Comment: I will like also to find a way to delete the properties from the class in similar way
so it will save the memory with all the extends classs.

Comment: user15388024's first comment is wrong, but their subsequent correction is right. JavaScript is fundamentally unlike nearly all other mainstream OOP languages in that it uses prototypical inheritance rather than class-based inheritance. This means that the parent class lives in the child class's prototype property, which you can manipulate at run-time just like any other property. In other languages class extension is a "special" construct, and the parent is not exposed as just another object property in that same way. This feature of JS is what allows NestJS's type helpers to work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just came across the same use case as you and here's how I did it:

```
const Omit = <T, K extends keyof T>(Class: new () => T, keys: K[]): new () => Omit<T, typeof keys[number]> => Class;
```

Then you can use it like so :

```
class Child extends Omit(Parent, ['propertyToDelete']) {}
```

[As you can see child only has one property now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEGSX.png) (it also works with methods).

The package from [@nestjs/swagger](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/tree/master/lib/type-helpers) has some nice helpers if you're dealing with a NestJS API. Their implementation is more complex so I guess they are keeping other stuff like their own property decorators (I am pretty new to Typescript so maybe I miss the point of all they are doing).

P.S: French guy tried to answer for first time with imperfect English so please be kind ^^

Comment: You are a Guinness!

Comment: This works! But suppose the parent class is a DTO with `class-validator` annotations, will the child class also inherit the validation rules set on the parent class?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think, I had to give up this "hack" because it doesn't inherit the `@ApiProperty()` decorators (or at least Swagger doesn't recognize them afterwards)

Comment: It worked for the typescript part, thanks

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way to do it:

```js
class Parent {
  propertyToKeep = 'hi';
  propertyToDelete = 'bye';
  constructor() {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    delete this.propertyToDelete;
  }
}

const myObject = new Child();

console.log(myObject);
/* OUTPUT:
  {
    "propertyToKeep": "hi"
  }
*/
```

Comment: I really think this is a decent way. but with low vote.

Comment: very nice -- Typescript is just a Javascript transpiler, so no need to overthink it when JS already has a solution

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. If you declare an attribute in a parent class, you can't restrict his visibility in a child class.

From the model design point of view, that doesn't make sense as well. The problem you are exposing here indicates that your class hierarchy is not well designed and you must rethink and redesign it.

Comment: -1: it is possible. 
+1: but i like your model design sight

Comment: This is the right answer. If you extend a class A, `instanceof A` will be true, but then you're breaking the expectations of an instance of A by disabling its methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Object.defineProperty` function, for make a restriction in descriptor, **enumerable** to **false** and `getter`, `setter` with specific condition, here a complete example:

```js
//A small example of how to make an invisible property in Child class.

class Parent{
 
 constructor(){
 
  this.propertyToKeep = "Visible";
  this.propertyToDelete = "Not visible in subclass child";
 
 }
}

Object.defineProperty(Parent.prototype, "propertyToDelete",  {enumerable: false,
 configurable: true,
 get: function(){
     if(!(this instanceof Child)){

        return this._propertyToDelete;
     }
 },
 set: function(v){
    
    if(!(this instanceof Child)){

        this._propertyToDelete = v;
    }
    

 }});

 Object.freeze(Parent.prototype);

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

//console.log(Child.prototype);

let chd = new Child();

console.log("Child: --------------------------------");

console.log(chd);

console.log(chd.propertyToDelete); //Undefined

console.log("Parent: -------------------------------");

let prt = new Parent();

console.log(prt);

console.log(prt.propertyToDelete); //"Not visible in subclass child"

/*let chdObj = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Child.prototype);

console.log(chdObj);*/


class SomeComponent{

  #child;

  constructor(child) {
    
    this.#child = child;

    

    console.log(this.#child); //{propertyToKeep: "Visible"}

    console.log(this.#child.propertyToKeep /*work*/);
    
    console.log(this.#child.propertyToDelete /*undefined*/);


  }
}


//Now i will invoke SomeComponent

console.log("SomeComponent: -------------------------");

let sc = new SomeComponent(new Child());
```

Comment: Thank but in this case I need to use it sometimes with the attribute and sometimes without.   
I need to used it in angular dependency injection. 
So no constructor use. 
I will check maybe I can go in with this to get my gol thank you very much